# placeholder in search bar on samsung galaxy displays on wrong side

Tags: html, css, cordova

i'm using this web editor example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MW7q6/

which enables you to see the input tag styled

```
text-align: right;
```

on iPhones and nexus the placeholder is displayed correctly on the right side, but on all samsung galaxy devices it's on the left side.

somebody know the reason? or how to solve this?

Comment: Anybody could provide a sample with browserstack?

Comment: I created a **[demo on browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/2224dd126df8cf76ff1ff53d4fa0917d9d1b2046)**. tested the fiddle on **Samsung Galaxy S I II III** and ... But it worked without any error, placeholder text is shown on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
direction: rtl;
```

to the input tag

and

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     direction: rtl;
}
```

anywhere in the css

Comment: the place holder is on top of the input in galaxy.
how i fix that?
tanks again

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: right;` will solve with rigth CSS selector

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
```